# Error: Can't get to call method from non-activity class - generates NullPointerException error

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-context

I have two classes: NewAppointment with activity xml file and GenerateTreatmentList which extends NewAppointment.
In the xml I have a button which should bring forth a AlertDialog list which is implemented in GenerateTreatmentLis as follows:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;

import android.content.DialogInterface;


public class GenerateTreatmentList extends NewAppointment {

public void generateList(){

    final int[] listTitle = new int[1];
    final String[][] listCategories = new String[1][1];
    final int[] categoryArray = new int[1];

    listTitle[0] = R.string.title_category;
    categoryArray[0] = R.array.categories;
    listCategories[0] = getResources().getStringArray(categoryArray[0]);

    chooseTreatmentList(this, listTitle[0], listCategories[0], true, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which) {
                // Abonamente category
                case 0:
                {
                    listTitle[0] = R.string.title_abonament;
                    categoryArray[0] = R.array.abonamente;
                    listCategories[0] = getResources().getStringArray(categoryArray[0]);

                    chooseTreatmentList(context, listTitle[0], listCategories[0], true, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            switch (which) {
                                //Abonament - Vacuum corporal
                                case 0:
                                {
                                    listTitle[0] = R.string.title_timp;
                                    categoryArray[0] = R.array.ab_vacuum_time;
                                    listCategories[0] = getResources().getStringArray(categoryArray[0]);

                                    // Extract the treatment name
                                    treatmentChosen = R.string.vacuum_corp_name;

                                    chooseTreatmentList(context, listTitle[0], listCategories[0], true, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            // Extract treatment duration
                                            switch (which) {
                                                // Abonament - Vacuum corporal - 60 min
                                                case 0:
                                                {
                                                    treatmentDuration = R.string.name_60_min;


                                                } break;
                                                // Abonament - Vacuum corporal - 30 min
                                                case 1:
                                                {
                                                    treatmentDuration = R.string.name_30_min;
                                                } break;
                                                default: break;
                                            }

                                        }
                                    });
                                } break;
                                // Abonament - Ultrasunete
                                case 1:
                                {

                                } break;
                                //Abonament - Microdermoabraziune
                                case 2:
                                {

                                } break;
                                //Abonament - Electrostimulator
                                case 3:
                                {

                                } break;
                                default: break;
                            }

                        }
                    });
                } break;
                // Tratamente category
                case 1:
                {
                    listTitle[0] = R.string.title_tratament;
                    categoryArray[0] = R.array.tratamente;
                    listCategories[0] = getResources().getStringArray(categoryArray[0]);

                    chooseTreatmentList(context, listTitle[0], listCategories[0], true, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    });
                } break;
                // Epilare category
                case 2:
                {
                    listTitle[0] = R.string.title_epilare;
                    categoryArray[0] = R.array.epilari;
                    listCategories[0] = getResources().getStringArray(categoryArray[0]);

                    chooseTreatmentList(context, listTitle[0], listCategories[0], true, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    });
                } break;
                // Masaje category
                case 3:
                {
                    listTitle[0] = R.string.title_masaj;
                    categoryArray[0] = R.array.masaje;
                    listCategories[0] = getResources().getStringArray(categoryArray[0]);

                    chooseTreatmentList(context, listTitle[0], listCategories[0], true, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    });
                } break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
    });

}

private static void chooseTreatmentList(Context context, int listTitle,
                                        String[] listElements,
                                        boolean OnClickListener,
                                        DialogInterface.OnClickListener selectedItemListener) {

    AlertDialog.Builder treatmentList = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    treatmentList.setTitle(listTitle);
    treatmentList.setItems(listElements, selectedItemListener);
    treatmentList.create().show();
}
}
```

The Dialog list should open another dialog list each time and so on until a certain point (did not finish all the options yet). It works fine if I move all the code from GenerateTreatmentList to NewAppointment class, but it is something that I am trying to avoid because I will over flow the class.

When I press the button, the app restarts on the phone and I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResourcesInternal(ContextThemeWrapper.java:127)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:121)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:542)
        at com.andygix.programarilucia.GenerateTreatmentList.generateList(GenerateTreatmentList.java:18)
```

Line 18:

```
listCategories[0] = getResources().getStringArray(categoryArray[0]);
```

At first I thought it was a missing context passing, but I tried a few methods and nothing worked. Unfortunatelly now I am stuck, but don't want to move this part to the NewAppointment class.

Any ideas?

Edit: Forgot to mention the call to the method from the NewAppointment class

```
GenerateTreatmentList getList = new GenerateTreatmentList();
getList.generateList();
```

Comment: You can't instantiate Activities, meaning you can't directly call methods on them.

Comment: Then any idea on how can I do this? I was thinking of making an activity for the GenerateTreatmentList class and create a custom list dialog, but I'm not sure if it will work and would like a second (or third) opinion.

Comment: I don't really even know what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I managed to find how to resolve the issue. I made the following changes:

In `GenerateTreatmentList` class I created a method with the class name and context as parameter.

```
private Context context;

    public GenerateTreatmentList (Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
```

Then, when trying to access a resource I also added the context before the path to the given string or array list

```
listCategories[0] = context.getResources().getStringArray(categoryArray[0]);
```

In the NewAppointment class, when trying to call the the non-activity one, I passed the context:

```
   public void chooseTreatment() {
        GenerateTreatmentList getList = new GenerateTreatmentList(this);
        getList.generateList();
   }
```

I know that my code looks sloppy and that's because I'm new to this thing. I usually write it in an expanded way, see if it works than try to simplify it.